# unpack 'tar' but change directory name to extract to

Tags: tar

```
tar -tf filename.tar
folder1/file
folder1/name
[...]
```

I'd like to extract **file** and **name** to, **folder2**. Can this be done as a one-liner?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use `-C` and `--strip-components` (See `man tar`).

#### Example:

```
mkdir FOLDER
# for remote tar file
curl -L ’remote_tar_file' | tar -xz -C FOLDER --strip-components=1

# for local tar file
tar -xzf FILENAME -C FOLDER --strip-components=1
```

#### Explanation:

The `-C` flag assumes a directory is already in place so the contents of the tar file can be expanded into it. hence the `mkdir FOLDER`.

The `--strip-components` flag is used when a tar file would naturally expand itself into a folder, let say, like github where it examples to `repo-name-master` folder. Of course you wouldn’t need the first level folder generated here so `--strip-components` set to `1` would automatically remove that first folder for you. The larger the number is set the deeper nested folders are removed.

Comment: I read `man tar`. Didn't spot `--strip-components`. nice one

Comment: tar-1.14 uses --strip-path, tar-1.14.90+ uses --strip-components. Maybe problem here?

Comment: I'd upvote this if it gave an example and not just the switches, as the [online manual states](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC35), 3 argument styles give rise to confusion.

Comment: Forgot the -f on tar -xz, me thinks. Failed for me. I thought I'd been using that for no reason all this time...

Comment: When the output of curl is piped into tar, there should be no single hyphen parameter (i.e., instead of `-xz - -C` it should just read `-xz -C`). A single hyphen usually acts as a filename and refers to using stdin instead of a file, but without a `-f` tar already uses stdin without an explicit `-`. In fact, it does not expect any filename in this case and providing one (even `-`) will trigger an error.

Comment: Nice example here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/how-to-choose-directory-name-during-untarring

Answer (score 24):

You can also use the `--transform` option for a bit more flexibility.  It accepts any sed replacement (s) operation.

For example, this is how I extract a Linux tarball to a new directory so I can apply a patch:

```
tar -xjf linux-2.6.38.tar.bz2 --transform 's/linux-2.6.38/linux-2.6.38.1/'
```